# How to return error message from a method that otherwise returns a collection

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, collections

It's more of a conceptual thing. My method is supposed to return a list of `Conferences`. But if there is an error, I just want it to send a String response or maybe a JSON response like `{err: 'Some error'}`.Offcourse following method throws compiler error for this line - `return e.getMessage();` . How to achieve this?

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/allconf", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public List<Conferences> getAllConf(@RequestBody Conferences conf) {
    List<Conferences> allConf = new ArrayList<Conferences>();
    try {
        allConf.addAll(confRepository.findAll());
    } catch(Exception e){
        return e.getMessage();
    }
    return allConf;
}
```

Comment: Do not return your error - just throw it.

Comment: If I just throw the error, it will be actually sent as a response to client?

Comment: No, the client will need to catch your custom exception and deal with it, assuming it's a valid business case.

Comment: @PM77-1 This is a REST service.

Comment: If you use own exceptions you can annotate them with `@ResponseStatus`. [Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-response-status-exception) guide

Comment: @DavidConrad - missed that. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: Check this out : https://www.toptal.com/java/spring-boot-rest-api-error-handling

Comment: You can do two things. You can return an `Optional` of the object you are wanting to return or you can throw the exception and catch it in your calling method.

Comment: @sapy please see my answer. This is as you should implement it https://stackoverflow.com/a/54083046/10426557

Answer (score 1, accepted):

e.getMessage() returns a String and you method is a Conferences List, use a new generic response class like

```
public class Response {

   private Object content;

   private String error;

   // getters and setters

}
```

and change your method

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/allconf", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Response getAllConf(@RequestBody Conferences conf) {

        Response resp = new Response();
        List<Conferences> allConf = new ArrayList<Conferences>();
        try{
            allConf.addAll(confRepository.findAll());
            resp.setContent(allConf);
        }catch(Exception e){
           resp.setError(e.getMessage());
        }
        return resp;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Have one option:

**Best solution** it is throw an exception:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/allconf", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public List<Conferences> getAllConf(@RequestBody Conferences conf) {
    List<Conferences> allConf = new ArrayList<Conferences>();
    try {
        allConf.addAll(confRepository.findAll());
    } catch(Exception e){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(e.getMessage()); 
    }
    return allConf;
}
```

And create an error handler to handle exception and how you wanna display it:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class CustomErrorHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(IllegalArgumentException.class)
    public void handlerIllegalArgumentException(IllegalArgumentException exception, ServletWebRequest webRequest) throws IOException {
        webRequest.getResponse().sendError(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.value(), exception.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: As tempting as the easy way sounds, it would still return 200 as HTTP status, which would technically not be correct (HTTP status codes exist for a reason). I would at least add some sort of disclaimer to that part of the answer.

Comment: @dunni yes, you are right, I edited it. but I saw that an answer was accepted :V and looks like fast and poor answer. :V well

Comment: To dunni's point the only way to send back a different HTTP status would be to use ResponseEntity with a different status based on the outcome. 

Here is a good link if that's the way you would like to do it:
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-response-entity